# What is the use of service.method attribute in Moqui?

Tags: moqui

I am not able to figure out the method in which I can use the service.method attribute in Moqui. Is this similar to that of service.invoke attribute in OFBIz which allows me to call the method form the file specified in the location.

I was not able to find any examples related to this anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The annotation in the XSD for the service.@method attribute says: "The method within the location, if applicable to the service type."

To expand on that, for Java classes this is the method within the class. For Groovy scripts you can call a method in the script (or Groovy class) instead of running the top-level of the script.

Comment: Can you add some code examples just for clearing the doubts regarding the syntax that should be used with each type of service (i.e. script, java, camel, interface etc)?